# TFLite Shared library generated through CMake not working

Tags: tensorflow, cmake, tensorflow-lite

System information :
Debian 10

Trying to TensorFlow Lite install from source:
TensorFlow Lite version 2.4.1.
Followed steps in tensorflow lite CMake build to build library on LInux host.

Describe the current behavior :
The default CMakeLists file creates static library. We want to generate a dynamic library through CMake
Only able to generate C++ TFLite static library

Describe the expected behavior:
Need to create C++ TFLite dynamic library.

Modified CMakeLists to generate a shared library. But the generated one is not working. Attached error message in the image.
[Modified CMakeLists file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4kh3.jpg)
[image: Error with TFLite C++ shared library version 2.4.1]

Comment: "But the generated one is not working" is not very useful description of the problem. Please, add to the question post more details about that problem. If you got an error message, then add it too. Also note, that Stack Overflow discourages using **images** for code. Instead paste the code into the question post as **text**. See also [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to generate C++ TFLite dynamic library.

But if you're going to use C API, you can generate C TFLite dynamic library.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#build_tensorflow_lite_c_library

Comment: Hi, Able to generate C++ shared-library through bazel with this command (bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so)  . But C++ CMake shared library is not working. Is there a fix and workflow to generate C++  CMake shared library